# Drawing an dodecahedron with vertexes at given coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics, polyhedra

I want to draw an (**edit**)dodecahedron with the vertex in the following coordinates:

```
 v={{-0.982247, 0, 0.187592}, {0.982247, 
 0, -0.187592}, {-0.303531, -0.934172, 0.187592}, {-0.303531, 
  0.934172, 0.187592}, {0.794654, -0.57735, 0.187592}, {0.794654, 
 0.57735, 0.187592}, {-0.187592, -0.57735, 0.794654}, {-0.187592, 
 0.57735, 0.794654}, {-0.491123, -0.356822, -0.794654}, {-0.491123, 
 0.356822, -0.794654}, {0.491123, -0.356822, 0.794654}, {0.491123, 
 0.356822, 0.794654}, {0.607062, 
 0, -0.794654}, {-0.794654, -0.57735, -0.187592}, {-0.794654, 
 0.57735, -0.187592}, {-0.607062, 0, 
 0.794654}, {0.187592, -0.57735, -0.794654}, {0.187592, 
 0.57735, -0.794654}, {0.303531, -0.934172, -0.187592}, {0.303531, 
 0.934172, -0.187592}}
```

The way I know to do it is with `GraphicsComplex` `Graphics3D[{Thick, GraphicsComplex[v, Line[i]]}]`

Think is that I don't know which vertex are conected by lines.

I can draw the coordinates by the comand:

e1 = Graphics3D[Point[v]]

[image]

And now I would know which vertex to join by rotating that figure if I had some way to get the coordinates from the plot or label the points as '1', '2', '3'

Some thoughts, in this line or any other?

Comment: `Nearest[v]` might help. So might `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"]` together with `FindGeometricTransform`.  If you figure it out, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks I solved it for this case, cause the ordering of the vertex was the same as `Short[i = PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "FaceIndices"]]`  then `Graphics3D[{Thick, GraphicsComplex[v, Line[i]]}]` saved my day. Other way I suppose you have to figure out how to rearrage the list of vertex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCount"] == Length@v

(* False*)
```

Yours isn't an Icosahedron

However, it's a **Dodecahedron** instead:

```
f = Nearest@v  
Graphics3D[Line /@ Flatten[MapThread[List, {f[#, 4], ConstantArray[#, 4]}] & /@ v, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### V10

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[
 ConvexHullMesh[v],
 MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> {PointSize@.02, Blue}, 1 -> None, 2 -> Opacity@.7}]
```

[image]

Comment: Feel free to use this `BoundaryMeshRegion[
 ConvexHullMesh[v],
 MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> PointSize@.02, 1 -> None, 2 -> Opacity@.2}]` because I'm still not sure what is OP goal ;)

Comment: @Kuba I saw your answer, but V9 here :( Thanks!

Comment: @Kuba  Thanks for the edit

Comment: I'm not able to apply BoundaryMeshRegion to ConvexHullMesh

Comment: @user10712 Welcome! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!